# Cancelling alarm from other class that the one which initiated it

Tags: android, android-alarms

I set alarm from one class using this code

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ClassOne.this, AlarmService.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ClassOne.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(currentDate.getTime());
long when = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, (7 * 24 * 60 * 60) * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Now I need to cancel the pending alarms from another class. Can I just use this code?

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(ClassTwo.this, AlarmService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ClassTwo.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManagerCancel = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManagerCancel.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Or there is a better/proper way to cancel pending alarms?

Comment: I have tested this and this works, but I am not sure if this is the right way to cancel pending alarm service. That is the main reason for initiating this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the `PendingIntent` are equivalent as the one you used to register the alarm, it doesn't matter where you call `cancel()` from. Two `PendingIntent`s are equivalent (`equals()` returns `true`) if the underlying intents and request codes are the equivalent.

Comment: I thought of this then I came to "underlying intent". The original intent calls `ClassOne+AlarmService`, while the other calls `ClassTwo+AlarmService`. Are they equal if the initiating class is different?

Comment: Yes, the first parameters is used to determine the package context, so as long as your in the same app (package), they are equivalent. Check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for details. (the full link just won't come up properly, see the 5th constructor)

Comment: You mentioned a "request code". Where is it? I cannot find any request code, except `PendingIntent.getService() requestCode`, but it is
Private request code for the sender (currently not used according to docs).

Comment: The docs are wrong, it is actually used and considered when comparing pending intents. `getService()/getActivitiy()/getReceiver()` all have it as a parameter.

Comment: I figured this out. I tested it and it actually recognizes this parameter as request code.